# fadeOut element when jquery slideshow is on #1

Tags: jquery, coda-slider

The site in question: http://notlaura.com/dev/smfa/index-all2.php

I want the 'back to list' button (`#to-list`) only to appear when the first panel of the Coda Slider is hidden. This works until the first panel is encountered with the arrow navigation. My code is:

```
    $("#to-list").hide();

    $("li.name,a#nl").click(function(event){        
        $("#to-list").fadeIn(900);
    }); 

    $("#to-list").click(function(event){
        $("#to-list").fadeOut(900);
    });
```

I tried checking for `$('a[href$="#1"]')` but the arrow hrefs are only `#`, so that doesn't work. Also tried a conditional for the URL with `window.location`, and checking if the panel is hidden, `if( $("#list").is(":visible") ) {}`

But no success. Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `window.location.hash`

```
$("li.name,a#nl").click(function(event){
    if(window.location.hash == "#1") {
        $("#to-list").fadeOut(900);
    } else {
        $("#to-list").fadeIn(900);
    }
});
```